# IBM Websphere MQ Server

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-rational

I am trying to create a MQ Server in Websphere Version 8 from IBM Rational Software Architecture. After navigating from Servers->ServerType->Websphere MQ Servers and clicking New button, gave the following fields for mandatory items

```
Name : stackMQServer
Websphere MQ Server Name : stackMQServer
Server TYPE : Queue Manager
Websphere MQ Host : localhost/1272.0.0.1
Websphere MQ Port : 1414 default
Websphere MQ Channel : SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
```

Error :

```
WebSphere MQ server stackMQServer connection test failed for WebSphere MQ queue manager stackMQServer. CWSJP0050E: An attempt to connect to WebSphere MQ queue manager or queue sharing group stackMQServer failed. The WebSphere MQ reason code is MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE (2059)..
```

Comment: I do not know about Rational, only MQ.  Can you confirm that "create a MQ Server" really means to define a new MQ queue manager with those parameters or just to setup a connection to a existing queue manager?  If it is the later then 2059 would be expected if there is no queue manager already defined and listening on the IP and Host and Port.  If it does actually create a queue manager, you could be hitting a default CHLAUTH rule that blocks access to `SYSTEM*` channels.  If you look at the queue managers errors/AMQERR01.LOG file it should provide more info on the cause of the 2059.

Comment: i am trying to define a new MQ Queue Manager with the above parameters

Comment: Then please take my suggestion and provide more info on the cause of the 2059.

Comment: It does mean that you are creating a connection to an existing queue manager. If you want to create an MQ server you will have to install the server software, it is not bundles with RD.
Start at: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-ubuntu/
to run a server in a container and go from there.